# How to do pattern matching with boxed enum?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, smart-pointers, stack-memory

i have an enum where i have to perform pattern matching. But since i am running the program on VM which has limited stack memory ( < 4Kb ), i allocated the enum on the heap using `Box`. But while performing pattern matching, i have to dereference it which causes it to get allocated on stack which i dont need. Is it possible to perform pattern matching on Boxed values?

I want to achieve something like below.

```rs
pub enum MyEnum {
  A,
  B,
}

let a = Box::new(MyEnum::A);
let value = match a {
  MyEnum::A => 1,
  MyEnum::B => 2 
}
```

This is the error that i get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/entrypoint.rs:119:9
    |
118 |     match a {
    |           ---
    |           |
    |           this expression has type `Box<MyEnum>`
    |           help: consider dereferencing the boxed value: `*a`
119 |         MyEnum::A => 1,
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found enum `MyEnum`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Box<MyEnum>`
                 found enum `MyEnum`
```

I tried dereferencing it as the compiler suggested, but since it allocated on stack while dereferencing, i could not use it. I want to match the enum without dereferencing it.

Comment: You should be getting an error that `MyEnum`'s body is an invalid definition for a struct.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, it was suppose to be enum. I was trying to create a minimized example of what i have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match on references too. This will simply reborrow boxed value and allocate at most a pointer on the stack.

```rust
pub enum MyEnum {
  A,
  B,
}

let a = Box::new(MyEnum::A);
let value = match &*a {
  &MyEnum::A => 1,
  &MyEnum::B => 2 
};
```

Comment: if suppose, `MyEnum::A` is of 1000 bytes, it would still allocate that on stack when matching right?

Comment: @DhruvDJain No, `&*a` obtains a reference to the contents of the box (not the box itself) and matches on that reference. No copy is made. In fact, a copy can't even be made -- if you try `*a` the compiler will emit an error telling you that `MyEnum` does not implement `Copy`.

Comment: @cdhowie in cases where there are nested pattern matching, what would be solution? Because in that case, the value would move but since its behind a reference it will throw an error.

Comment: @DhruvDJain No it wouldn't. Match ergonomics will bind the extracted values as references.